# How did 'consideration' semantically shift to mean 'something given in payment'?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

1. What semantic notion connects the bolded meaning beneath with all the others that aren't related to recompense? To me,  nouns like [remittance or solatium (if we prefer an uncommon term)](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/compensation) fit the bolded meaning more intuitively.

> mid-14c., *consideracioun*, "a beholding, looking at," also "a keeping in mind," also "contemplation, reflection,"
>    from Old French *consideracion* (12c., Modern French *considération*) and directly from Latin *considerationem* (nominative *consideratio*) "consideration, contemplation, reflection," noun of action from past-participle stem of *considerare* "to look at closely, observe" (see [consider](https://www.etymonline.com/word/consider?ref=etymonline_crossreference)).
>
> Meaning "a taking into account, act of paying attention to" is from late 14c.; that of "examination, observation" is from early 15c.. Sense of "thoughtful or sympathetic regard" is from c. 1400. Meaning "that which is or should be considered" is from late 15c. **Meaning "something given in payment" (as recompense for service) is from c. 1600.**

2. Which [semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)) is this?

The bolded meaning looks related to meaning of 'consideration' in English contract law. See Paul Richards, [*Law of Contract*](http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/educator/product/Law-of-Contract/9781292176109.page) (13 edn 2017), pp. 68 Bottom-69:

> [...] it has become preferable today to think in terms of consideration amounting to a claimant buying a defendant’s promise by performing some act in return for it.
>   Alternatively, the claimant may purchase the defendant’s promise by the furnishing of a counter-promise. This modern approach was summed up by Sir Frederick Pollock (1950) in
>   *Principles of Contract*, where he defined consideration as:
>
> > An act or forbearance of one party, or the promise thereof, is the price for which the promise
> >     of the other is bought, and the promise thus given for value is enforceable.
>
> This definition was approved by the House of Lords in ***Dunlop Pneumatic Tyre Co. Ltd v
>   Selfridge and Co. Ltd*** [1915] AC 847 and is regarded as being more representative of the
>   doctrine of consideration in the modern commercial contract than the nineteenth-century
>   concept of benefit and detriment.

Comment: The term's use in law has its roots in common law decision making by English courts going back to long before the 1700s. I don't know precisely how.

Comment: FYI it's also not a question about linguistics. It *might* be a question about legal history, tracing first attestations in common law documents.

Comment: The answer may be contained in J.H. Baker "Origins of the “Doctrine of Consideration, 1535-1585", referring to *Lucy v. Walwyn* (1561).

Comment: Read this article: https://books.google.com/books?id=Yl4vAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=afterthoughts+on+consideration+canadian+law+review+vol+1&source=bl&ots=69tv_R3j37&sig=AACagZD8K4-IZehBkulYj71Y-9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-iPTPp_LdAhVE4VQKHYpyCuMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=afterthoughts%20on%20consideration%20canadian%20law%20review%20vol%201&f=false

Comment: @ohwilleke Isn't legal history on-topic?

Comment: The question as to how the specific legal meaning of "consideration", in the sense of "something given in payment", has shifted, would be a question of history and thus on-topic.  However, it is probably too broad to ask about it across all jurisdictions.  The question of how "consideration" came to be used i the sense of "payment" *in the first place*, or what linguistic phenomenon this exemplifies, is one of etymology and I would argue it is not on-topic.  I don't know if it's *linguistics* per se, but it is certainly *language*.  I would suggest taking it to English.SE.

Comment: I have to disagree: this isn't a question about language or linguistics, it's about the history of the doctrine of consideration. The language part is trivial.

Comment: The doctrine of consideration goes back to Roman law. https://www.jstor.org/stable/753085?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents but, obviously, the word in a language that didn't exist during the Roman era does not.

Comment: @ohwilleke the direct etymon *consideratio* did however exist in Latin, of course.  I am not aware that it had a similar sense of "payment," and I rather doubt that it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ames reviews the doctrine and the rise of "consideration" in "[The History of Assumpsit. I. Express Assumpsit](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1321512.pdf)", stating that after Henry VIII, "it became the practice, in pleading, to lay all *assumpsits* as made *in consideratione* of the detriment or debt". A person assumes (*assumpsit*) an obligation for some cause (*causa*). The assumption of obligation is made having considered the debts or detriment. Once "consideration" becomes a technical legal concept (as it did in the 17th c.), what remains variable is the prevailing doctrine associated with the term.

Pollock in ['Afterthoughts on consideration'](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yl4vAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=afterthoughts%20on%20consideration%20canadian%20law%20review%20vol%201&source=bl&ots=69tv_R3j37&sig=AACagZD8K4-IZehBkulYj71Y-9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-iPTPp_LdAhVE4VQKHYpyCuMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=afterthoughts%20on%20consideration%20canadian%20law%20review%20vol%201&f=false) suggests the conceptual development was from general contemplation, to deliberate decision, then including the grounds for a decision, and finally and most relevant to the current legal concept "that which induces a grant or promise'.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Where did you find a PDF of 'Afterthoughts on consideration'? Or  how else did you read it?

Comment: At this point, I don't remember how – generic Google-fu, I guess. Pollock is one of those "names" in history of English law.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please elaborate the semantic shift: (1) from 'general contemplation' (which falls under the general meaning of 'consideration') to 'deliberate decision' (which doesn't fall under it)? (2) from 'deliberate decision' to 'the grounds for a decision'?

Comment: Can you please respond in (by editing) your answer? A chain of comments is more cumbersome to read.

Comment: I found the PDF of 'Afterthoughts on consideration' at https://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?collection=journals&handle=hein.journals/lqr17&id=425&men_tab=srchresults.

Comment: I uploaded Pollock's 'Afterthoughts on consideration'  - https://mega.nz/#!C8YmyYLT.